# Ruby on Rails String DoubleQuotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a string `a = "Hello"`

I want to **remove double quotes** of this String. I am using gsub but its not providing me the correct result.It gives me string with double quotes.

Comment: What do want to do with this? String must have `double qoutes` or `single qoute` in ruby.

Comment: I just want Hello.

Comment: String always comes inside single or double quotes in ruby. Your variable value is hello & when you show this value in view , it will always show hello without any quote

Comment: please mention the case where you are trying to use it. Ex: `puts a` would write to your console as `Hello`

Comment: Where you want to use `Hello`? If you use this or perform it as `String`, why do want to remove `double qoutes`? What is the reason why do you want to remove `double qoutes`?

Comment: I am doing this in Active admin.

Answer (score 0):

`a = "Hello"` is how you define a string in Ruby. When using it somewhere else, the double quotes will not be there anymore.

Example:

```
a = "Hello"
greetings = a + " Prafull"

puts greetings
=> Hello Prafull
```